# Excel Index and Match search with IF criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i made code to find some unique IDs in my excel sheet

My sheet has 3 colums.
Column 1. Unique ID
Column 2. Availability in format of "0" or "1"
Column 3. Search criteria, value ex. 123, 506, 1002

```
=IF(INDEX(MATRIX,MATCH(Cell in Column3,Column3,3)>0,INDEX(Matix,MATCH(Cell in Column3,Column3,0),1),"no sample")
```

All unique samples that have "1" are available, those with "0" are already used.

I need to search for some values(ex 1002) and assign Unique ID that has that value and is still available ("1" in column 3).

There are many that same values with different Unique IDs. So if the first one in my table was used, it should check 2nd, 3rd usw. and if there are any samples left with that value. It should say me "no sample"

Could someone give me a tip how to write this in excel?

Example: i have one sheet in which i have values that are needed.
I use that code to find free Unique ID's like: re24wa545, B105423 usw.

```
1 Column/2 column/3 Column
d105643/    0    / 1456
W105643/    1    / 1456
X105643/    0    / 1456
A40320/    0    / 1000
A40321/    0    / 1000
A40322/    0    / 1000
A40323/    1    / 1000
```

So i use in my new sheet column with those values 1456 and 1000 and try to find free sample with "1" in base sheet

Comment: Please give an example of the end result you are looking for

Comment: Will be that enough for you?

Comment: Why not use a pivottable? Or even an advanced filter?

Comment: because i need to serach for over 100 different values at once. So i need to make it with one simple move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Array formula

With an array formula (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the formula in a cell):

```
=INDEX(Sheet3!$A$3:$A$9,MATCH(TRUE,Sheet3!$C$3:$C$9=G2*Sheet3!$B$3:$B$9=H2),0)
```

[image: Formula]

**2) Table with filter**

Example:

[image: Using filter]

**3) Pivottable with filter**

[image: Pivottable]

Comment: That Array formula will do, but it gives only last postition in my Array ex.A40323 and too if that position is not available or i even if i look for other value

Comment: It should return the first available match on the search criteria